# How to generate fixed length binary representations using Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using code below I'm attempting to convert String to binary representation :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}

val sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (0.0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  (1.0, "Logistic regression models are neat")
)).toDF("label", "sentence")

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setBinary(true).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(5)

val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
val idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)

val rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)

rescaledData.rdd.collect()
```

This returns :

[image]
Above code based on example from https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf

But the binary representations are of different lengths.

Whats difference between rawFeatures and features ?

How to generate fixed length binary representations ?

Update :

So `(8,[0,1,5],[1.0,1.0,1.0])` represents `[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]` Is there an API method to extract the `[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]` representation ?
Reading the API doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF this does not appear available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the binary representations are of different lengths.

There are not. These are all `SparseVectors` of size 5. The first number in the representation is the size of the `Vector`, and two arrays represent indicies and values of the non-zero entries.

> Whats difference between rawFeatures and features ?

`HashingTF` uses [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) and output vectors represent more or less the count of each token.

`IDF` computes [inverse document frequenc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Inverse_document_frequency_2).

> How to generate fixed length binary representations ?

ditto

**Edit**:

Converting to dense representation is possible, for example with `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

val toDense = udf((v: Vector) => v.toDense)
```

but **almost never desired**. In normal situation `HashingTF` uses very high number of features (2^20 by default, by higher values are not uncommon) to avoid hash collisions, but individual `Vectors` are highly sparse. Therefore this representation is very efficient. Converting to dense can increase memory consumption orders of magnitude, without any information gain.